# Change the release process from SNAPSHOT to build number

Tags: jenkins, build.gradle, gradle-release-plugin

Currently we are using axion-release-plugin to control our release process. Now we would like to drop the SNAPSHOT and introduce the build number in our release process. So that we can achieve CI.

Basically currently we are using version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and now we need something like 1.0.0-BUILDNUMBER or 1.0.BUILDNUMBER from Jenkins.

Please provide any solution or plugin we can use with gradle.

Comment: did you see http://devdeeds.com/auto-increment-build-number-using-gradle-in-android/ and https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-implement-build-number-in-gradle/18768/4?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually quite happy with [nebula-release-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin) developed by NetFlix. It can generate a unique version number based on branches and tags in your git repo.

By default it counts with using git flow, but you can reconfigure the behaviour. Take a look :)